# SIGSEV while using DDD (Data Display Debugger)

Tags: c, unix, segmentation-fault, scanf, ddd-debugger

It's my first time using DDD and i'm pretty inexperienced with the subject matter in question (c in unix environment) so i might be overlooking something.
I'm receiving a segmentation fault when i try to fscanf from a file, which doesn't occur in a normal gcc compilation. The function is the following:

```
void read_config(){
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("config.txt","r");
    fscanf(fp,"TRIAGE=%dDOCTORS=%dSHIFT_LENGTH=%dMQ_MAX=%d ",&data.triage,&data.doctors,&data.shift,&data.mq_max);
}
```

and after reading the fscanf line it give the following message in DDD:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0xb7e58e1e in
>   __isoc99_fscanf () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/lib.so.6

I can't figure out what might be causing this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ensure the input file fits the scanf, and the pointers given as argument fits the types, and that they have enough space to store what has to be stored... Btw i prefer using fgets + strtok

Comment: Maybe the file doesn't exist in the current directory, or you are not allowed to read it? (errno/perror is your friend)

Comment: @wildplasser the file is in the same directory as the executable and the c file, had i've added `chmod("config.txt", 0644);` to ensure that permissions are in order. Also i added `if(fscanf(fp,"TRIAGE=%dDOCTORS=%dSHIFT_LENGTH=%dMQ_MAX=%d ",&data.triage,&data.doctors,&data.shift,&data.mq_max)==EOF){
      perror("Couldn't read from file");
    }`

Comment: How about `if(!fp)‌​{ perror("Couldn't open file%s", the_file); }`

Comment: @wildplasser sorry for the late response. It printed out no such file in the directory, but the file is there. Maybe i need the file in a different directory because i'm using DDD?

Comment: Please see the answer by @Employed Russian . The cwd can be different from  the directory where the executable is located.

Comment: @wildplasser yes i've seen it and accepted it as the right answer. Thank you also for taking time to help me on such a rookie issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't figure out what might be causing this issue.

Look in the debugger at the value of `fp`. It will be `NULL`.

You should *always* check return value of *every* system function you call.

> the file is in the same directory as the executable

That doesn't matter. What matters is what is your *current* directory when you are calling `fopen`.

Unless you instructed `DDD` to change to the directory where `config.txt` resides, chances are `DDD` is running from some other directory.

Comment: Yup that was the problem. Thanks! Pretty embarrassing it was such a rookie mistake but i guess it will never happen again which is good. Thanks again.